# New to C++, can't figure why my program doesn't recognize these functions

Tags: c++, linked-list

It keeps on saying "function contains is never used". I've never posted before, so if you have advice on how I can get my point across better please let me know.

[Edit] I'm trying to post only code that I wrote myself. I wrote these 3 functions, and only the first one works:

This is what's in the CPP file:

```
template<class ItemType>
ItemType LinkedList<ItemType>::replace(int position, const ItemType& newEntry)
{
    std::cout << "replacing at position " << position << " with " << newEntry << std::endl;
    Node<ItemType>* curPtr =this->getNodeAt(position);
    curPtr->setItem(newEntry);
    return newEntry;
}  // end replace


// TODO: LinkedList<ItemType>>::contains
template<class ItemType>
bool LinkedList<ItemType>::contains(const ItemType& entry)
{
    for(int i = 0; i<this->getLength(); i++)
    {
        Node<ItemType>* curPtr = this->getNodeAt(i+1);
        if(curPtr->getItem()==entry) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// TODO: LinkedList<ItemType>>::containsRecursive
template<class ItemType>
bool LinkedList<ItemType>::containsRecursive(Node<ItemType>* node,const ItemType& entry){
    if(node == nullptr){
        return false;
    }
    if(node->getItem()==entry){
        return true;
    }
    return containsRecusive(node->getNext(),entry);
}
```

and this is what's in the header

```
ItemType replace(int position, const ItemType& newEntry);
bool contains(const ItemType& entry);
bool containsRecursive(Node<ItemType>* node,const ItemType& entry);
```

and when I try to call it in the driver, it doesn't appear on the dropdown. Just the other functions in the program such as:

replace, remove, insert, getNodeAt, getEntry, getLength, clear, and isEmpty

and it basically says the function doesn't exist, when I call it in the driver
with

```
listPtr->contains("hello"); //doesn't work, turns red
listPtr->replace(1,"hello"); //does work
listPtr->containsRecurssive(headPtr, "hello")//doesn't work, turns red
```

The contains is red, and it says,
"No member named 'contains' in 'ListInterfacestd::basic_string<char>'"

And it still says in the .h and the .cpp file that
"Function 'contains' is never used"

But all the other functions work fine.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file is worth a read. You haven't really included enough code to diagnose your current problem. Consider a [mcve].

Comment: Oops, the second image is wrong. If I add an actual string it does the same thing

Comment: Images of code and errors are not helpful. I didn't even look at them. Copy/paste the text into your question.

Comment: There is not really enough code there. I am not entirely sure why you would have a templated member function in the `.cpp` file. Usually the templates go in the headers.

Comment: I guess I would like to know how to show what I mean without posting the whole code. I'm fine with doing it but half of the code is starter code, and I don't think it is looked down upon to post other peoples code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which type you passed to `LinkedList` to construct `listPtr`, but most likely that type and the type passed to `contains` are not the same (although they might look like the same).

Passing `"hello"` might be interpreted by the compiler in different, as `std::string` but also as `const char *`.